# Brick parapet material

Tags: masonry

Can someone please help. I'm trying to determine if stone or metal coping is preferred for brick parapet wall in terms of weather-ability.

Answer (score 0):

Galvanized or aluminum copings are better. Even for parapets that already have stone or concrete coping to preserve the coping they cover it with some metal sheeting.

Copper is used in quality jobs mostly in historical buildings sparingly because of the cost.

The reasons metal sheeting is the preferred method:

- Continuous flashing with easy to shop build shedding details, grooves and drip lips, and joint seams. a practical way of accommodating changes in the width and height of the parapets.
- Durability and low maintenance.
- Ease of remodeling and modifications down the road.
- flexibility to accommodate the thermal expansion.

Stone and concrete will eventually crack at the seams and let the rain and freezing damage it.

**EDIT**

I have attached a diagram detailing galvanized coping on a concrete and a brick parapet wall.

[image: Galvanized flashing]

In the lower picture notice, the stone coping on parapet has failed to protect the building

[image: stone coping leaking]

Comment: My understanding is stone has thermal expansion properties similar to brick masonry and normally doesn't present problems with differential movement when applied as coping. Metal has very different thermal expansion properties than brick masonry.

Comment: So I thought if it's in terms of weather-ability, similar materials is preferred?

Comment: Yes Even for brick, metal coping is better. the flashing details provide for differential expansion by having enough play at the standing seams. you may check some flashing details.